# Managing users with dual-stack IPs (IPv4/IPv6)

Tags: node.js, ip

I have a NodeJS app that identifies users through a number of methods, e.g. email authentication, cookies, IP.
With the IP I can for instance do rate-limiting.

The problem is that nowadays a single client can connect through IPv4 or IPv6, basically giving users "two" IP addresses. This makes it much harder to restrict users through IP.

I tried connecting to a NodeJS test server multiple times with a single client (my laptop), and sometimes it connected using my IPv4 IP, other times with my IPv6 IP.

How would you go about handling an issue like this? Thanks.